biblatex incompatible with natbib
I get this error: The 'natbib' package and biblatex are incompatible. I am not sure what I should do, your help is appreciated.
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[varg]{txfonts}
%%%%
\usepackage{lmodern}

% number format
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sn-bibliography.bib}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{longtable}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
%\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%  meant for continuous numbers
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}% 
%\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}%
\newtheorem{example}{Example}%
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}%
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}%
\raggedbottom
\begin{document}
\title[Article Title]{A Survey on Recent Methods}

%\author{Author One \quad Author Two \quad Author Three\\ Institution}
%\href{}{ {\{e***.***, s***.a\}}@uga.edu}}
\author*[1]{\fnm{E***} \sur{B***}}\email{e***.b***@uga.edu}
\author[1]{\fnm{S*** K***} \sur{A***}}\email{s***.a@uga.edu}
\affil{$^{1}$School of Computing}


\abstract{Machine learning, deep learning, and NLP methods on knowledge graphs are present in different fields and 
have important roles in various domains from self-driving cars to friend recommendations on social media platforms.

This is just a random text
\end{document}

P.S: I TRIED TO COMPILE THE ORIGINAL TEMPLATE WITHOUT ADDING ANY PACKAGES MANUALLY BUT THE CITATIONS PRINT AS QUESTION MARK:
\documentclass[sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Numbered Reference Style 

\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%
%%%%
\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%  meant for continuous numbers
%%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]% meant for sectionwise numbers
%% optional argument [theorem] produces theorem numbering sequence instead of independent numbers for Proposition
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}% 
%%\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}% to get separate numbers for theorem and proposition etc.

\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}%
\newtheorem{example}{Example}%
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}%

\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}%
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}%

\raggedbottom
%%\unnumbered% uncomment this for unnumbered level heads

\begin{document}

\title[Article Title]{Article Title}


\author*[1,2]{\fnm{First} \sur{Author}}\email{iauthor@gmail.com}

\author[2,3]{\fnm{Second} \sur{Author}}\email{iiauthor@gmail.com}
\equalcont{These authors contributed equally to this work.}


\author[1,2]{\fnm{Third} \sur{Author}}\email{iiiauthor@gmail.com}
\equalcont{These authors contributed equally to this work.}

\affil*[1]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{100190}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}



\abstract{The abstract serves both as a general introduction to the topic and as a brief, non-technical summary of the main results and their implications. Authors are advised to check the author instructions for the journal they are submitting to for word limits and if structural elements like subheadings, citations, or equations are permitted.}
\bibliography{sn-bibliography}% common bib file
%% if required, the content of .bbl file can be included here once bbl is generated
%%\input sn-article.bbl


\end{document}



Welcome! The error really speaks for itself. You cannot use both packages in the same document. A quick look at your preamble suggests you should remove natbib since it won't like \addbibresource. But it isn't possible to be certain that's the easiest fix because you've not shown how you're producing your bibliography. But that's my guess.

Note that I've edited your tags because overleaf is irrelevant. Overleaf is just your editor.

What's the reason for wishing to be able to load the natbib citation management package? Is it that your document employs \citet and/or \citep instructions to generate citation call-outs? If so, just load the biblatex package with the option natbib=true.

Off-topic: The txfonts package is quite old, appears to be unmaintained, and is known to have some problematic properties in math mode. Do yourself a favor and replace \usepackage[varg]{txfonts} with \usepackage[varg]{newtx}. (If you employ an older TeX distribution, use \usepackage{newtxtext} and \usepackage[varg]{newtxmath}.) And, don't load the lmodern package as well. Conversely, if you do wish to load lmodern, don't run \usepackage[varg]{txfonts} since it'll be clobbered by the subsequent \usepackage{lmodern} directive.

Your not working code snippet does not show, where you or the class or another package loads natbib. However using both, natbib and biblatex is the issue here. So you either have to eliminate the usage of natbib or remove biblatex. And if you need more help, you should show a minimal working example resp. MWEB so we would be able to reproduce the problem and suggest how to solve it.

It may be that your document class or another package is loading natbib.  If that is the case, then you need to "unlead" natbib somehow. Example: \documentclass[nonatbib]{elsarticle}.

It's worth keeping in mind though that if the document class loads natbib for you (as seems likely here, since the code you've shown does not appear to load it), then there might be a (good) reason for that. So maybe you should not be using biblatex after all - or you should not be using this particular class. ...

... Classic examples are publisher classes/templates. Those usually require certain citation/bib styles that are implemented in the templates already [often using natbib]. In those cases, you definitely shouldn't try to roll your own solution with biblatex. Check the documentation and follow its advice.

@Elika Can you please add which class you use?

@cabohah Thanks, I edited the question.

@Vebjorn Thanks, it didn't work. (no pdf produced)

@moewe can you please check it here? thanks. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/719634/question-mark-instead-of-citation

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Sure! \documentclass[sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl}

@Elika As the other commentors have guessed correctly, your class loads packages which are incompatible with biblatex. Better not use biblatex with this class.
